# C Dynamic memory allocation using structures

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, structure, allocation

I am trying to allocate memory in my group_list function.
The idea of the group_list function is to sort Node*-elements (which are lists) of the same length in another list.
(An example sort of using mathematical notation: group_list( ["aa", "b", "cc", "d", "eee"] ) = [["aa", "cc"], ["d"], ["eee"]] )

If I want to allocate n Node*-elements in a list, I would simply use calloc(n, sizeof(Node*)); but how to allocate the memory for the list of Node*-elements?

The list can possibly have just one element, which includes n Node*-elements, or n elements which include just one Node*-element and everything in between.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 typedef struct Node {
    void* value;
    struct Node* next; // self-reference
 } Node;

 //constructor function
 Node* new_node(void* value, Node* next) {
    Node* node = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = next;
    return node;
 }

 Node* group_list(Node* list) {
    Node* new_list = calloc(??);

    return NULL;
 }

 int main(void) {
    Node* list1 = new_node("a", new_node("bb", new_node("ccc", 
 new_node("dd", new_node("e", NULL)))));
    group_list(list1);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: To the extent I understand what you're asking, you want a list of lists to use the same representation as a list of elements. However, because you're using `void *` for the value type, you're throwing away all the type information, and you can't tell by looking what you're dealing with — one `void *` looks much the same as any other `void *`. I think that leaves you with intractable problems, and that you need to use a different mechanism which somehow tells you what you're dealing with. I'd not be using `void *` in the visible interface — though I might use them in the private implementation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
The Node*-list is a list of strings and the group_list function should create a list, that includes list of strings.

Comment: I'm no wiser. Can you draw an ASCII art (or other) diagram that shows how you think the pointers work in your list of lists output? I can see what the sorting does, but I don't see how you represent it using the structure you've shown (and I'm not sure that you do either, or you'd not be asking). How do you know whether the `value` pointer points to a string node or a list node? What I'm tending towards is a statement along the lines of "I don't think it can be done using the structures you've shown", but I'm seeking clarification on what you're hoping for before doing so. Edit the question.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you could use another `struct` as a wrapper to your list which would contain a `list-count` and then an array of values that holds the number of elements in each list. For your example `["aa", "cc"], ["d"], ["eee"]` your `list-count=3;` and (if you allow your array index to equal the number of characters (+1)), then your array elements would hold `1, 2, 1` (1 - `"d"`, 2 - `"aa","cc"`, 1 - `"eee"`). That way you have a count for each to alloc/realloc as needed.